# Feeds importer. Only imports a certain amount then stops

Tags: caching, feeds, cron

I have been attempting to import 5,000+ pieces of content from a CSV file using the feeds module. I have it set up to import 130 items every cron run and i have cron running every hour.

All is good for the first few hours. I go to sleep and then wake up, and it is no longer running.

I have my cache clearing every 6 hours. is it possible that clearing cache kills the communication with feeds and stops the import record?

Is it a simple setting change within feeds?

I cannot monitor it completely to see when this issue stops exactly since my imports are suppose to be spread over 48 hours on each hour.

Update: If I run cron manually over and over again, it will reach 100%.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron might help here

Answer (score 0):

you can check your php config php_memory_limit must be at least 128M and max_execution_time 120

also check the error logs go to admin/reports/dblog and check for the errors logged by the server, maybe you can find the problem there

Also make sure you are getting all the errors so you can make a better debug in your issue

Change settings in your site

You can show all errors by adding a few lines to your local testing site's settings.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
//Note:  Do not include the opening and closing PHP tags when you copy this code
```

In addition, navigate to Administration→ Configuration→ Development → logging and errors and select "All messages". (This sets $conf['error_level'] = 2; .)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to setting.php

**$conf['feeds_process_limit'] = 2000;**